# How does SSLScan determine the cipher suite list that a server supports?

Tags: security, ssl

I just want the high level working. From what I observed through my packet capture I saw that there was no change in ordering of the cipher suite.

Answer (score 0):

The server never tells you which cipher suites it supports. The client sends its supported ones in ClientHello, and the server picks one of them and informs the client with ServerHello. To determine the cipher suite list supported by the server, you need to test each cipher suite one by one.